# CSS Multi-Column issue: one paragraph with unequal heights

Tags: html, css, paragraph, multiple-columns

Is there any chance to have one 2 column paragraph with different heights in CSS? I have a fix height and would like to fill it left to right column.

[this is what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0b8a.png) vs. [what I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l26YG.png)

I played around with `column-count` and `column-fill` but it ended up in the trash.

Answer (score 0):

`column-count=2` will merely divide the entire set of text into two halves of equal height and hence that is why you are getting that result.

You can achieve the desired result by creating separate divs for both columns within the parent div.

Alternative solution without column-count:

```css
.main {
   width:100%;
}
.main > div{
   width: 48%;
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: top;
   text-align: justify;
}
.main > div:nth-child(1){
   margin-right: 2%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <div class="main">

    <div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat,vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam;</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p> est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius.</p>
  </div>
</div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately the parapragh text comes right out of MySQL, so the length varies